# Is there a standard separation between mic and speaker headset jacks?

Tags: headset

Taking the bog-standard GA headset jacks, where one is for the mic and the other for the headset speakers, is there a standard dimension between the two? Or is it just anything goes so long as they're far enough apart, but not too far?